# monitoring of java application in appdynamics

Tags: java, javaagents, appdynamics

I have my java application up and running. I want to import that application in Appdynamics for monitoring. Can any one please suggest how to import java applications in appdynamics.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to setup the AppDynamics Controller (should be hosted on a separate  machine), then you need java agents on the machine with the application. 
[image]

You need to wire the application with the Java agent, e.g. like this

```
/usr/bin/java
-Dappdynamics.controller.hostName="my-appdynamics-controller-url"
-Dappdynamics.controller.port="8090" \
-Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName="MyAppName"
-javaagent:/appdynamics/appserver-agent/javaagent.jar
-Dappdynamics.agent.tierName="my-tier-name"
-Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName="my-node-name"
-jar myapp.jar
```

Now the Java agent sends application information to the controller. Take a look at the documentation. https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO43/Getting+Started

The application will automatically be available in AppDynamics and you can see the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to host the controller, you can get a SAAS account here. https://www.appdynamics.com/free-trial/ .

Once you get a SAAS account lookup the account name and account key in the welcome email and use the instructions in the email to add JVM args to your app as shown. Don't forget to set the account name and account access key args: -Dappdynamics.agent.accountName -Dappdynamics.agent.accountAccessKey .